# Multiple cells actions UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm developing timer app and I made custom actions in cells for start/pause and reset timers. I used closures for this. This is my code for custom cell:

My model:

```
class Timers: NSObject, Codable {
  var name = ""
  var id = ""
  var seconds = 0
  var editSeconds = 0
  var isStarted = false

}
```

class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
var startaction: (() -> Void)? = nil
var pauseaction: (() -> Void)? = nil
var reseteaction: (() -> Void)? = nil

@IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var timerTime: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var startPauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var resetButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func timerStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let timerStart = self.startaction {
        timerStart()
    }
}

 @IBAction func timerReset(_ sender: UIButton) {
     if let timerReset = self.reseteaction {
        timerReset()
    }
}


}
```

And this is part of my code for timers Controllers:

```
var timer = Timer()

func runTimer(for cell: TimerTableViewCell, with item: Timers) {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = item.name
    content.body = "Time is up!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(item.seconds), repeats: false)
    let identifier = item.id
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: {_ in
        if item.seconds < 1 {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel
            let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
            label.textColor = .black
            label2.textColor = .black
            label.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.seconds))
            item.isStarted = true
            cell.startPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        } else {
            item.seconds -= 1
            let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel
            let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
            label.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 227.0/255.0, green: 61.0/255.0, blue: 39.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            label2.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 227.0/255.0, green: 61.0/255.0, blue: 39.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            label.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.seconds))
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sleep")
        }
    })
        }



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timers.items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timer", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell
    let item = timers.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.timerLabel.text = item.name
    cell.timerTime.text = formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.seconds))

    if let color = UserDefaults.standard.colorForKey(key: "Color") {
        cell.startPauseButton.backgroundColor = color
        cell.resetButton.backgroundColor = color
    } else {
        cell.startPauseButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 60.0/255.0, green: 60.0/255.0, blue: 60.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.resetButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 60.0/255.0, green: 60.0/255.0, blue: 60.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    let secSettled = item.seconds

    cell.startaction = {
        if item.isStarted {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            item.isStarted = false
            cell.timerLabel.textColor = .gray
            cell.timerTime.textColor = .gray
            cell.startPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)

            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [item.id])
        } else {
            self.runTimer(for: cell, with: item)
            item.isStarted = true
            cell.startPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
            }
    }

    cell.reseteaction = {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        cell.timerLabel.textColor = .black
        cell.timerTime.textColor = .black
        if item.editSeconds > 0 {
            cell.timerTime.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(item.editSeconds))
            item.seconds = item.editSeconds
        } else {
            cell.timerTime.text = self.formattedTime(time: TimeInterval(secSettled))
            item.seconds = secSettled
        }

        item.isStarted = false
        cell.startPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [item.id])
        }

    cell.showsReorderControl = true

    return cell
        }
```

When I run mulitple timers it start on multiple cells. How I can fix this problem? Can anybody help me with any solution?

[image]

Comment: `cellForRow` is the wrong place to declare `Timer` instances. Run the timer in the model. And `viewWithTag` to access UI elements is outdated for a long time. As you got a custom cell anyway use outlets.

Comment: You have tied your timers to your cell, but cells are reused as you scroll. Your timer needs to be part of the data model. Due to timer inaccuracy you will probably also find it is better to use a `Date` to track start/end time rather than decrement good a counter.

Comment: I made timers be part of data model and update my code above. But anyway timers not works as they should and run on multiple cells being reused.

Comment: And may be you can provide example code how timer can be part of my data model?